# nextjs middleware does not save cookies for the browser

Tags: next.js, cookies, nestjs, middleware

I have a nestjs application where the endpoint has this code `response.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {httpOnly: true, signed: true, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24})` and on the nextjs client in the middleware I send a request to this endpoint

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { AuthConstantsEnum } from './constants/auth.constant'
import { authService } from './services/auth/auth.service'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const refreshToken = cookies().get(AuthConstantsEnum.REFRESH_TOKEN)?.value

    if (refreshToken) {
        const data = await authService.getSession()
    }
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'],
}
```

As a result, I see an entry in headers Set-Cookie, how to save cookies in the browser
there is an alternative, but it's bad

```
//middleware.ts

const response = NextResponse.next()

...

response.headers.set("Set-Cookie", data.headers.get("Set-Cookie"))
```